# Examples of abelian group with some property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Somebody told me there exists a torsion-free abelian group $G$, such that $G$ is isomorphic to $G\oplus G\oplus G$, but $G$ is not isomorphic to $G\oplus G$. But he does not tell me such a concrete example, since he dose not know too.

> I do not know if there is a well-known example about this.
>   Could anyone give such an example? Or any references?

Thanks.

Comment: I think such an example is due to ALS Corner.

Comment: If you have access to mathscinet or Maths Reviews, try MR0169905, where a much more general result is given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Geoff Robinson mentioned, you may find it [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3)

P.S. I don't know why I cannot write a comment now. Something is wrong with my PC!